# Xcode writing to file issue

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to help my son with a Programming C++ for Engineers course. I got him set up with Xcode 13.1 on his iMac but I've never used it myself. That was working great until his first assignment that required writing output to a file. We created a new Command Line Tool project and then used the File->New->File... option to create an Empty file. After doing so, selecting that file and looking at the info on the right side of the window shows that the Full Path is pointing to the directory where his main.cpp file is. Yet, when running his code nothing was being written to the file. I had assumed that just referencing the file name in his code would cause it to use a local reference and look in the same directory as main.cpp. After much Googling I found a reference that said to go to Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme... then select the Options tab in the window that opens and change the Working Directory from "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" to the directory containing the main.cpp file. That got the programming working correctly. My questions are:

1. Is there a preference setting that would tell it to always use the current project directory so that we don't have to change this every time?
2. Where does "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" point to?
3. What should we be doing differently?

Comment: if you want to write into a specific directory then its best to use an absolute rather than a relative path

Comment: I think that's the way to go when using a big IDE. For college learning, an IDE gets in the way almost as much as it helps. My recommendation would be to install homebrew, and spend the time learning a CLI tool like vim or emacs or even nano. CLI experience looks a lot better on a resume than a particular IDE. Especially in today's containerized and cloud world where more often than not all you have is a terminal. I will warn, it does take time. It will feel slower at first. But as you get up to speed on the basics, it pays off quickly.